# If $k$ shoes are selected from $n$ pairs of shoes, what is the probability that there is exactly one pair among the chosen shoes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In wardrobe there are $n$ pairs of shoes. We take $k$ shoes $k \leq n$. What is the probability that:

(a)Among chosen shoes there is at least one pair.

(b)Among chosen shoes there is exactly one pair.

(c)Among chosen shoes there is exactly one pair if we know that among chosen shoes there is at least one pair.

Order of sample space is ${2n \choose k}$

(a)Calculate complementary event, among chosen shoes there are zero pairs, there are ${n \choose k}2^k$ possibilities to probability of event A is $1-\frac{{n \choose k}2^k}{{2n \choose k}}$

(b)First we choose which pair we take then from $n-1$ pairs left we take $k-2$ shoes such that we take no pairs so there are $n{n-1 \choose k-2}2^k$ possibilities so probability of event B is $\frac{n{n-1 \choose k-2}2^k}{{2n \choose k}}$

(c)Note that event $B \cap A$ is exactly event $B$ so probability of event C using conditional probability formula is $\frac{P(B)}{P(A)}$

Comment: Your solutions look fine to me.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "checking solution" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: how would you title this question?

Answer (score 2):

*Under the  assumption  that $k$ is even.*

A comendable effort when so many questions come without the slightest hint of an effort, but you have made a mistake in part (b) which will also carry over to part (c)

P(event B) should be  $= \Large{n\cdot\binom{n-1}{k-2}\cdot2^{k-2}\over \binom{2n}{k}}$

because the last factor in the numerator will apply only to the $(k-2)$ shoes chosen

Comment: Why do we need the assumption that $k$ is even?

Comment: @DS: Have to leave immediately. Shall respond on return. Maybe I hadn't thought it through.

Comment: whenever you read: I think the answer is correct, only there is no need of the first line

Comment: @DS: **(1)** Which first line are you referring to ?  **(2)** If $k$ is even, you can choose one $L$ or $R$, that is why $2$ choices from each pair chosen. But if there is an odd single also, the $2$ factor won't be there if we choose that shoe

Comment: (1) "_Under the assumption that k
 is even._". (2) I didn't understand what would happen if $k$ is odd

Comment: thank you for the correction on exponent, however I think assumption about $k$ being even is not necessary, there always will be 2 choices L and R becuase there are $n$ pairs so $2n$ shoes

Comment: @romperextremeabuser: The *total* number of shoes $2n$ is, of course even, but you are choosing $k$ *shoes*, not *pairs* of shoes, so certainly $k$ can be either odd or even.

Comment: Ifk is odd what happens? Imo everything is okay. I pick $k-2$ shoes out of $n-1$ pairs, so I pick $k-2$ pairs out of $n-1$ and then for each $j$ from $1$ to $k-2$ I choose one of two shoes from previously selected pair

Comment: @romperextremeabuser: You are not picking $(k-2)$ **pairs** from $n-1$ pairs, you are picking $(k-2)$ **shoes** which will be an odd number if $k$ is odd.

Comment: im picking pairs from which I pick shoes

Comment: You are picking *randomly*.